# localizable.strings not working with Arabic string

Tags: ios, localization, arabic

I created a Localizable.strings file in XCode and then 2 languages in it.(english + Arabic )

I filled up these files with the language translations, but the just show translation in english, when I start with Arabic the key appear!

in my code :

```
NSLocalizedString("title", comment: "")
```

Localizable.strings(english)

```
"title" = "Error" ;
```

Localizable.strings(Arabic)

```
      "title" = "خطأ" ;
```

Comment: Do you prefer objctive c or swift?

Answer (score 1):

I careated sample one and tried in Objective C.I got it.

I set "title" = "خطأ" in  Arabic Localization files

> "title" = "عنوان";

Now I have to change English to Arabic.

First I set the design in storyboard

[image]

Then Click Project.Choose Localization in Info

[image]

If you click the +(Below Localization) it shows the pop up view

[image]

Now choose Arabic.When click Arabic it shows window.You should click finish.

[image]

We need to create the string file for the localization now.I set string file name as **LocalizationArabic**

[image]

Once you create the String file it looks like below.

[image]

Then click File Inspector when pressing LocalizationArabic string file.Now click the Localization.It shows Empty Check box Arabic and English like below.

[image]

Here we must check the check box.Also when we check the check box the LocalizationArabic folder creates with three string files like below

[image]

Then I entered the language which I want to translate from English to Arabic in string file.

[image]

Finally I created the Header file for the Localization Language

[image]

The Header file name is LanguageHeader.It looks like below.

[image]

Now the code part starts here

First the Localization class of NSObject class

Localization.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LanguageHeader.h"

@interface Localization : NSObject
+(Localization *)sharedInstance;
+(NSString*) strSelectLanguage:(int)curLang;
+(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key;

@end
```

Localization.m

#import "Localization.h"
    int currentLanguage,selectedrow;
    @implementation Localization

```
+(Localization *)sharedInstance
{
    static Localization *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Localization alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}


+(NSString*) strSelectLanguage:(int)curLang{
    if(curLang==ARABIC){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    currentLanguage=curLang;
    NSString *strLangSelect = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    return strLangSelect;
}

+(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *path;
    NSString *strSelectedLanguage = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    //When we check with iPhone,iPad device it shows "en-US".So we need to change it to "en"
    strSelectedLanguage = [strSelectedLanguage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"en-US" withString:@"en"];
    if([strSelectedLanguage isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"en"]]){
        currentLanguage=ENGLISH;
        selectedrow=ENGLISH;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    }
    else{
        currentLanguage=ARABIC;
        selectedrow=ARABIC;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"];
    }
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:@"LocalizationArabic"];
    return str;
}

@end
```

Then ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Localization.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    Localization *localization;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;

- (IBAction)actionChangeLanguageToArabic:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize lblTitle;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    localization = [Localization sharedInstance];
    lblTitle.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"title"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionChangeLanguageToArabic:(id)sender {
    [Localization strSelectLanguage:ARABIC];
    lblTitle.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"title"];
}

@end
```

Above code works perfectly.

Output Screen shot are below

When run the app first

[image]

After clicking the button

[image]